How to automate console.log random string with word (or selection) under cursor?
I am using this code snippet for adding console.log:
imap cll console.log()<Esc><S-f>(a
" Console log from visual mode on next line, puts visual selection inside parentheses
vmap cll yocll<Esc>p
" Console log from normal mode, inserted on next line with word your on inside parentheses
nmap cll yiwocll<Esc>p

I want to transform this to add console.log with random string, for example 20 characters
for example:
console.log('adfnkanwkefj34543519kjskdlafnawklefasdf <some_space_here> ')
and
console.log('adfnkanwkefj34543519kjskdlafnawklefasdf <some_space_here> ', variable)
Also i wanted to know , what does the <S-f>(a do ?

What did you try?

Answer
For inserting a random string you could do:
function! RandomString(n)
  let ret = ""
  for i in range(a:n)
    let j = rand()
    let c = nr2char(char2nr('a') + (j % 26))
    let ret .= c
  endfor
  return ret
endfunction

imap <expr> cll "console.log('" . RandomString(20) . "', )<Esc><S-f> a"

" Console log from visual mode on next line, puts visual selection inside parentheses
vmap cll yocll<Esc>p

" Console log from normal mode, inserted on next line with word your on inside parentheses
nmap cll yiwocll<Esc>p

How it works
I propose to use an expression mapping <expr> in an expression mapping the left hand size is not a literal string sent to Vim when the mapping is triggered but and expression that is evaluated when the mapping is triggered and the string sent is the value of the expression.
Since it is an expression the literal part has to be quoted either by " or by '. I select " because we need ' in the result.
The . (or ..) is the string concatenation operator in VimScript.
The full expression contains the concatenation of:

The first part of the expression console.log('
The call of RandomString(20)
The second part of the expression ', )
The operation that move back the cursor before the parenthesis <Esc><S-f> a (or `))

Remarks
The <S-f>(a is equivalent to F(a:

F( search for the previous open bracket (()
a switch back to insert mode

As @Friedrich mention in this case since we should only skip one character (the closing brace )) we could replace <Esc><S-f> a' by `
imap <expr> cll "console.log('" . RandomString(20) . "', )<Esc><S-f> a"

Could be replaced by:
imap <expr> cll "console.log('" . RandomString(20) . "', )<C-o><left>"


Can you please describe this: what this parts means? '" .  and this  . "' ...why have you added the " sign asfter a?
this moidification gives such output console.log(variable'pnkzrkcqtccnrviichau') 
how to make it console.log('pnkzrkcqtccnrviichau     :', variable)

Thanks for the feedback. I have adapted the solution to fit better what I understand from your need.

thank you! now its worked
can you please describe how it works:
Can you please describe this: what this parts means? '" . and this . "' ...why have you added the " sign asfter a?? =)
Changed it to imap <expr> cll "console.log('" . RandomString(20) . "  :', )<Esc><S-f> a" 

BTW, isn't all this <S-f> a business just a fancy way to say <Left> or <C-O>h?
